# Behat appends additional url when redirecting

Tags: symfony, redirect, behat

I'm using Symfony 3.4 with FOSUserBundle and Behat for testing.

**Config & code:**

```
Behat config:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            sessions:
                default:
                    symfony2: ~
                javascript:
                    selenium2: ~
            browser_name: firefox
            show_auto:    false
            base_url: 'http://my-virutalhost.test'

        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                env: "acceptance"
                debug: "true"


    Scenario: I execute enpoint address with wrong redirect code
      When I go to the url "/redirect/code1code2"
      Then I should be redirected to url "http://some-page-here.com"

/**
 * @When /^I go to the url "([^"]+)"$/
 */
public function iGoToTheUrl($url) {
    $this->lastResponse = $this->getSession()->visit($url);
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getContent();
    //var_dump($url, $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getCurrentUrl());
}

/**
 * Checks, that current page PATH matches regular expression.
 *
 * @Then /^(?:|I )should be redirected to (?P<pattern>"(?:[^"]|\\")*")$/
 */
public function iAmRedirectedToUrl($pattern) {
    $this->assertSession()->addressMatches($this->fixStepArgument($pattern));
}
```

**Problem:**
Somehow Behat appends to my redirect url http://some-page-here.com /login from my app, which creates link: http://some-page-here.com/login. I don't know why it creates such address for redirect. 
**-- EDIT --** 
When I check the content of page $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getContent() I see code of the login page

**-- Edit --**

1. /login - it's my application login
2. I want to make redirect to
   outside page, not in a page inside of my application and check if the final address is the address of the page from outside redirect

My security config:

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/redirect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: What are your security settings? can you update your code?

Comment: Have you tried the same scenario manually?

Answer (score 0):

I would look closer at Firefox, because I don't think Behat is the culprit here.

From what I can make out, what is happening is:

1. Behat tells Firefox to navigate to 'http://my-virutalhost.test/redirect/code1code2'
2. This URL responds with a HTTP redirect to 'http://some-page-here.com/'
3. Firefox honours the HTTP redirect but for some reason appends /login to the URL.

I would look into the responses that Firefox is getting to ensure that the correct redirect url is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Is your redirect ok ? If your content page show the /login, then `When I go to the url "/redirect/code1code2"` must send to this page.

As you use the MinkExtension, did you tried with the default Step `When I go to '/redirect/code1code2'` ?

Or have you access to the page if you do directly `When I go to the url 'http://some-page-here.com'` ?

And for the http://some-page-here.com/login stuff, It's strange... If your page is able to show you the /login content, then it must say it has access to http://my-virutalhost.test/login